# after ajax post show multiple divs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display multiple divs after an ajax post.The following code inserts the text but not the existing div I'm trying to call.  Please advise on how to do this.

```
$('#FormContainer').html(data).fadeIn("slow").append('#close-footer');
```

Comment: Do you mean it's not fading `#close-footer`?

Comment: first append `#close-footer` to `#FormContainer` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery executes in the order in which you call the functions.  If you are trying to fade in `#close-footer`, you must add it before your `fadeIn` call.

```
//Add HTML data
$('#FormContainer').html(data)
    //Append footer
    .append($('#close-footer'))
    //Fade in element
    .fadeIn('slow');
```

This is essentially the same as calling the functions separately.

```
//Add HTML data
$('#FormContainer').html(data);
//Append the custom div
$('#close-footer').appendTo('#FormContainer');
//Fade in #FormContainer
$('#FormContainer').fadeIn("slow");
```